# Why do my Python POST calls return 404?

Tags: python, xml, api, request

I am trying to POST a new product on fetchapp API (REST API) with Python. However, I have been reading the API doc and trying to figure it out, but I keep getting an 404 error. This is what the API doc say and this is what I have.

**API doc:**

```
All requests require basic authentication. To make a proper request,
you must set the authorization header of your request and supply
the generated string. The string is your personal key and token with
a colon ("demokey:demotoken") converted to a base-64 string. For
example...

"demokey:demotoken".to_base64 is ZGVtb2tleTpkZW1vdG9rZW4=

Then, place the string into the authorization header of your HTTP requests...

GET /api/v2/orders HTTP/1.1
Host: app.fetchapp.com
Authorization: Basic ZGVtb2tleTpkZW1vdG9rZW4=
Content-Type: application/xml

Please make sure to set the Content-Type header to 'application/xml'.

POST to create the specified product...

/api/v2/products
/api/v2/products/create
/api/v2/products/create.xml
For example...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product>
    <sku>1</sku>
    <name>Carrot Juice</name>
    <price type="float">10.00</price>
    <files type="array">
        <id>4443443</id>
        <id>4443444</id>
    </files>
</product>
```

**What I have:**

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
import json
from oauthlib.oauth1 import SIGNATURE_TYPE_QUERY, SIGNATURE_TYPE_BODY
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder
import time
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


url = 'http://www.fetchapp.com/api/v2/products/create.xml' 
headers = {"Accept": "application/xml"} 

auth=HTTPBasicAuth('demokey', 'demotoken')
data = {'sku': "CJ0001", 'name': "Carrot Juice", 'price type="float"': "1.00"}
r = requests.post(url, auth=auth, headers=headers, data=data, verify=True)

print r#.text
```

Comment: Your API is expecting XML, so you need to convert the data to XML first.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: sounds like a good point, but if one did not convert to XML first, would one get a 404? I imagine one would get a 500 instead.